# c# entity-framework object reference exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exception, object-reference

i have some difficulties with the following exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Code-First Migration at EntityFramework MVC5

```
public class Driver
{   
    [Key]
    public int NumberId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }

    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }

}
```

the Configuration:

```
namespace f1app.Migrations.F1app
{
    using Data;
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<f1app.Data.F1appContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            MigrationsDirectory = @"Migrations\F1app";
        }

        protected override void Seed(f1app.Data.F1appContext context)
        {

            context.Teams.AddOrUpdate(
                t => t.TeamName, DummyData.getTeams().ToArray());
            context.SaveChanges();

            context.Drivers.AddOrUpdate(
                d => new { d.FirstName, d.LastName }, DummyData.getDrivers(context).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

and the Initial Create:

```
namespace f1app.Migrations.F1app
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class InitialCreate : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Drivers",
                c => new
                    {
                        NumberId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        FirstName = c.String(),
                        LastName = c.String(),
                        Age = c.String(),
                        TeamName = c.String(maxLength: 30),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.NumberId)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Teams", t => t.TeamName)
                .Index(t => t.TeamName);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Teams",
                c => new
                    {
                        TeamName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 30),
                        City = c.String(),
                        Founded = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.TeamName);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Drivers", "TeamName", "dbo.Teams");
            DropIndex("dbo.Drivers", new[] { "TeamName" });
            DropTable("dbo.Teams");
            DropTable("dbo.Drivers");
        }
    }
}
```

than get some dummy data for the drivers to get into the table....

```
public static List<Driver> getDrivers(F1appContext context)
{
    List<Driver> drivers = new List<Driver>(){
        new Driver{
            NumberId=5,
            FirstName="Sebastian",
            LastName="Vettel",
            Age="29",
            TeamName=context.Teams.Find("Ferrari").TeamName,
        },
        new Driver{
            NumberId=44,
            FirstName="Lewis",
            LastName="Hamilton",
            Age="32",
            TeamName= context.Teams.Find("Mercedes").TeamName
        },
        new Driver{
            NumberId=19,
            FirstName="Felipe",
            LastName="Massa",
            Age="36",
            TeamName=context.Teams.Find("Williams").TeamName
        }
    };
    return drivers;
}
```

and using the PM Console for the Update - `update-database -ConfigurationTypeName f1app.Migrations.F1app.Configuration`. But only the table for the teams work fine, the Drivers Table doesn't get any data.... Any idea why?

Comment: Initial guess would be that the `context.Teams.Find("Ferrari").TeamName` lines are failing due to the `Find` not returning any data.  Are there Teams with these keys in the context?  Could you also add your code for `DummyData.getTeams()`

Comment: your `getTeams` code is missing.

Comment: your `TeamName=context.Teams.Find("Williams").TeamName` is weird. `TeamName="Williams"` should be enough

Answer (score 1):

you have a missplaced

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

that is:

```
protected override void Seed(f1app.Data.F1appContext context)
    {

        context.Teams.AddOrUpdate(
            t => t.TeamName, DummyData.getTeams().ToArray());
        context.SaveChanges(); // <----------------------

        context.Drivers.AddOrUpdate(
            d => new { d.FirstName, d.LastName }, DummyData.getDrivers(context).ToArray());
        //should be here:
        context.SaveChanges(); // <----------------------
    }
```

one is enough. I let both for the illustration.

Comment: sorry, i've tried but nothing really has change, still the same error-exceptions after running the package manager console command -  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: thats the end of the msg i get from the pm console after running the update command:  .....    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I think the problem is somehow connected with the references or something.... dont know - trying to understand how the c# and .net MVC are working right now....

Comment: Sorry everyone.... found it - was some minor text error, missmash that i've done..... forget it - solved!